# Could not find blob error while serving file through GCS

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to serve zip file via Blob ,stored in GCS. But I am getting this error"SEVERE: Could not find blob:BlobKey: encoded_gs_key:XYZ"

I have also tried the given code in this link to make sure I have right ACL on objects and I am successfully able to run this code:https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/migrate

```
  java.io.PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter( );

    out.println("before");

    try{
                GcsFilename fileName = getFileName();
                BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
                out.println("after");
                BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey(
                    "/gs/"+ fileName.getBucketName() + "/" + fileName.getObjectName());
                out.println("before");
                out.println(blobKey);
                blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

         out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
           resp.setContentType("application/zip");
           resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world Blob");


}

private GcsFilename getFileName() {

    String bucketname = "androidbucket";
    String filename = "test.zip";
    return new GcsFilename(bucketname, filename);
  }
```

Help me here !!   Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: This error only happens in the development server. Right now there's no support for serving blobs stored in Cloud Storage in the Java devappserver.

Comment: @SebastianKreft Could you please tell me other method to achieve the same. All I need to do is read zip file in GCS and send it to my android App.Thanks!!

Comment: Serving blobs from Clous Storage does work in production. It doen't in the devappserver. If you still need it to work in the devappserver you can user the GCS client https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/. See the example https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/java/example/src/com/google/appengine/demos/GcsExampleServlet.java.

Comment: @SebastianKreft Sorry to bother you again But I have tried that code before and I always get this error "No such file: GcsFilename("myBucketName", "myzipfile.zip")"..I again tried with the example sent by you and I get the same error..FYI: I have hardcoded my bucketname and filename instead of extracting from httpRequest..Could you please just help me this time..thanks

Comment: The example works if you created the file in Cloud Storage using the GCS client. The GCS client will not talk to the real Cloud Storage, so if your file lives in the real Google Cloud Storage you won't be able to easily get it from the devappserver.

Comment: Yea I have manually uploaded it to the GCS using " Google Cloud Storage Manager." :(..what do I do now..Its getting complicated..any other way out..I really need to get this done..Actually I need this to implement with my In APP BILLING(as a downloadable content) in Android App. So I need to store nearly 200 file with each purchase..There is no point of storing these files using GCS client in this case. Any suggestions..?? I am really getting nervous now..:(

Comment: This DOES work in production. Why are you running this in the devappserver?

Comment: My bad..I got confused with the word "production" ..I deploy and ran my script to app engine and it did work..Thanks a lot for your patience and support..!!:))))